# Is there a way to set the language for emails in firebase?

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-admin, pyrebase

I am making a small registration form using *firebase*, for this I use the *pyrebase* package, and I have a need to set the language for emails (password reset, registration, etc.) and also so that incoming messages have the language I need (https://APP.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/action?mode=verifyEmail&oobCode=...&apiKey=...&lang= **fr**), how can I do this?